# UsernameNotFoundException: Login form in Spring Boot + Spring Security doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a login form with Spring Security and Spring Boot, but it cannot find the user in the database. It just gives me the error when I put in the credentials. The registration form works though.
You can take a look at the whole project here: https://github.com/ashofthephoenix/Blog/tree/master/src/main/java/com/paulthemenace/blog

It also gives me this:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.full_name as full_nam2_2_, user0_.password as password3_2_, user0_.username as username4_2_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=?
```

I am using UserRepository:

`@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
     User findByUsername(String username);
}`

my implementation of UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepo;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

public UserDetailsServiceImpl() {
    super();
}
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    log.debug("Authenticating {}", username);
    final User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    if( user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    } 
    return new UserPrincipalImpl(user);
}


}
```

implementation of UserDetails:

```
public class UserPrincipalImpl implements UserDetails {

private final User user;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public UserPrincipalImpl(User user)  {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return user.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
}
```

markup code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/login.css" 
th:href="@{/css/login.css}"/>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="form">
<form method="post" th:action="@{/users/login}" class="login-form">
<p th:if="${param.error}"> Invalid username or password.</p>
<div><label for="username"></label></div>
<input type="text"  placeholder="username"/>


<div><label for="password"></label></div>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"/>


<div><input type="submit" value="Login"/></div>

</form>
</div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

LoginController:

```
@Controller

public class LoginController {


@RequestMapping(value = "users/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model) {

    return "users/login";
}
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin().loginPage("/users/login").permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/public/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");

}

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new 
DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return authProvider;

}
}
```

Thanks for the help. If I was not specific enough, I am sorry, but this issue is just killing me. If you're willing to help, then please tell me what information I didn't provide, and I'll give it to you.

Comment: please post the error stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login form elements are missing name attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
```